# Jenkins on Windows get stuck when git plugin execute ssh git-upload-pack

Tags: windows, git, azure, ssh, jenkins

I'm trying to setup Jenkins on Windows server running in Azure.
I've install Jenkins, git and git-plugin on Windows 2012.
I'm trying to clone a very small repository from BitBicket and in Jenkins console I can see this line:

On the server itself there is a process of ssh that is hang with this command line:
`c:\CI\Git\bin\ssh.exe -i "c:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\ssh663898192536328409key" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@bitbucket.org "git-upload-pack'mycompany/myrepo.git'"`

When I try to run this command in window cmd.exe I get this response, then the process stuck waiting for input and if I type something it exit with `protocol error` message:

```
00cbe160a5e558047c6dxy2d00694874365997d14f5 HEAD multi_ack thin-pack side-band
side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/1.8.5.2
003fe160a5e558047c6dcc37d00694874365997d14f5 refs/heads/master
0000
```

NOTE: When I git clone the same repository from git bash everything works great.

Comment: Where did the SSH executable come from?  Check the Windows Event log to see if there is any more information in that.  I'd also check the Windows Firewall Settings to see if there is anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the root cause but I did manage to get around it for now by generating a new key-pair **WITHOUT password**
For now it is enough and later I'll try to add password to the key-pair file.